# FSharpList<string> to IList<string> to XML

Tags: c#, f#, c#-to-f#

Using a code to convert `IList<T>` to an `FSharpList<T>` then write the list values to a XML.

```cs
public static class Interop
{
    public static FSharpList<T> ToFSharpList<T>(this IList<T> input)
    {
        return CreateFSharpList(input, 0);
    }

    private static FSharpList<T> CreateFSharpList<T>(IList<T> input, int index)
    {
        if(index >= input.Count)
        {
            return FSharpList<T>.Empty;
        }
        else
        {
            return FSharpList<T>.Cons(input[index], CreateFSharpList(input, index + 1));
        }
    }
}
```

I use the above code to make my own list

```cs
var fsharp_distinct = distinctWords.ToFSharpList();
var distinct_without_stopwords = Module2.stopword(fsharp_distinct);

foreach (string wd in distinct_without_stopwords)
    colwordfreq.Root.Add(new XElement(wd));
```

Infact, the XML is written too but just before exiting the loop it gives a `System.NullReferenceException`. But when a F# function returned a `Tuple<string, int>` using the same code I had no problems writing the Tuple values to a XML.

**EDIT:** I was not correct in the above question. The null point exception actually came from this code:

```cs
foreach (Tuple<string, int> pair in list2)
    colwordfreq.Root.Element(pair.Item1).Add(new XElement("freq", pair.Item2));
```

But when I added the condition

```cs
if (colwordfreq.Root.Element(pair.Item1) != null)
```

It doesn't give that exception.

Comment: I think the exception is from another section. I found that out on debugging.

Comment: @pad I edited the question. The null reference came from the tuple that returned the word frequencies.

Comment: Why don't you just add `pair.Item1` to the root node before adding `pair.Item2` to `pair.Item1`? In this way, you are safe and don't have to create the first string list.

Comment: @pad I have already added nodes to the XML before. Now I am trying to search for nodes and add children. Here I am not adding new nodes hence, I put the null condition. Still testing the application, I may need to change it later.

Comment: basically the application calculates the rankings of a bunch of documents using TFIDF for a keyword query. I have two XMLS. One to store word freq of each doc and another to store word freq for the whole collection.

Comment: You can just use `SeqModule.ToList` to convert from IList to F# list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example is a bit incomplete, but if `colwordfreq.Root.Element(pair.Item1)` returns `null` for some words, it probably means that you did not add that element previously. Maybe you need to add elements by writing something like:

```cs
foreach (Tuple<string, int> pair in list2) 
  colwordfreq.Root.Add                                // Add element to the root
    (new XElement(pair.Item1,                         // with the name of the word
                  new XElement("freq", pair.Item2))); // ... and the count
```

Aside, when you're calling F# code from C#, it is worth checking out the [F# component design guidelines](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/fsharp-component-design-guidelines.pdf). One of the suggestions there (which I strongly recommend to follow) is to avoid using F# specific types (like `FSharpList`) from C#. These are really designed for F# and are hard to use correctly from C#.

You can add a simple F# wrapper function that exposes the functionality using `IEnumerable`, which will be a lot easier to use from C#:

```ml
let rec stopword a = 
    match a with 
    |"the"::t |"this"::t -> stopword t 
    |h::t ->h::(stopword t) 
    |[] -> [] 

module Export = 
  let StopWord (inp:seq<_>) = 
    (inp |> List.ofSeq |> stopword) :> seq<_>
```

Then you can just call `Export.StopWord(en)` from C# without explicitly dealing with F# lists.

Comment: Thanks for the F# wrapper and the comp design link. I was looking for similar information. Infact, in the XML Im just trying to add children to existing nodes. If there isn't an existing node I am not adding it. That's why I put the null condition.